# JavaScript click Function play mp3s, not loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I would like to create a series of functions, that store mp3 files that will play when clicked on. *Eg*. I would like, say, click #3 to play a certain sound or mp3, and click #5 etc, and so forth.

```
    var a1_Events = [newsound1, newcoolersound2, coolestsound3],
        a1_c = 0;

        function newsound1(){

        // I would like to trigger a mp3 here. But not loop.
}

        function newcoolersound2(){

        // I would like to trigger a mp3 here. But not loop.
}

        function coolestsound3(){

        // I would like to trigger a mp3 here. But not loop.
}

    $('#area1').click(function(){
       a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so, I think I have a solution; but it appears a little bulky -- hoping there is something a little better; but my plan of implementation is including the below nested in a div and displaying the button via show / hide `onClick` within the functions area above.

```
//mp3 File 1
<audio id="id1" src="01.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="document.getElementById("id1").play()">Play</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById("id1").pause()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: I think that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I did it previously:

```
document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML=
  "<embed src=\"ding.wav\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" ><source src=\"ding.ogg\"><source src=\"ding.mp3\"><source src=\"ding.aac\"></embed>";
```

You can put files of any format (just beware that some browsers don't supoort a certain format).Another option is to put this code in a "div" element and then delete it after the sound has played.

Comment: Thanks @Paul so something like implementing a 'show / hide' for a div containing that code?

Comment: That won't work because you have to make a new element every time you want to play the sound. Try just printing a new element every time an event is triggered.